# Filter a JSON document in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath

I have a JSON reply from a GitHub repository with a list of possible downloads for a certain release (the `assets` array in the document).

I want to get the **browser download URL** when the `name` of an asset ends with `x64.AppImage`.

In Ansible, the filters are built apon [`jmespath`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) and using its terminal tool, I can query the url with the following expression:

```
assets[?ends_with(name, 'x64.AppImage')].browser_download_url
```

With the following playbook, the JSON document is queried and stored in the `json_reply` variable.

```
---
- hosts: local
  tasks:
    - name: Get list of Rambox releases
      uri:
        url: "https://api.github.com/repos/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/latest"
        body_format: json
      register: json_reply

    - name: Filter reply
      debug: URL -> "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ json_reply.json | json_query(json_filter) }}"
      vars:
        - json_filter: assets[?ends_with(name, 'x64.AppImage')].browser_download_url
```

However, executing this gives the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nIn function ends_with(), invalid type for value: latest-mac.json, expected one of: ['string'], received: \"unknown\""
}
```

Where `latest-mac.json` is the first object in the `assets` array.

How can I make Ansible to iterate over all the `assets` array and apply my filter?

**PS:**

If instead of querying if the `name` ends with a word I specify it directly, the filter works:

```
assets[?name == 'Rambox-0.5.13-x64.AppImage')].browser_download_url
```

---

**JSON example:**

```
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/8001922",
  "prerelease": false,
  "created_at": "2017-10-04T21:14:15Z",
  "published_at": "2017-10-05T01:10:55Z",
  "assets": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/assets/4985942",
      "id": 4985942,
      "name": "latest-mac.json",
      "uploader": {
        "login": "saenzramiro",
        "id": 2694669
      },
      "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/download/0.5.13/latest-mac.json"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/assets/4985640",
      "id": 4985640,
      "name": "Rambox-0.5.13-x64.AppImage",
      "uploader": {
        "login": "saenzramiro",
        "id": 2694669
       },
       "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/download/0.5.13/Rambox-0.5.13-x64.AppImage"
    }
  ],
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/saenzramiro/rambox/tarball/0.5.13"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem of type errors in JMESPath filters is discussed in [issue 27299](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299#issuecomment-331068246).

You can use this [patched json_query.py](https://gist.github.com/berlic/3b733390901625092796c7871d8fc23b) filter plugin.

Or apply double conversion to your object as a workaround: `| to_json | from_json |`.
This will convert object to JSON (thus plain strings) and back, so json_query will treat strings as supported type.

Comment: On Ansible 2.4.3 I get the following error when the patch is incorporated: class CustomFunctions(jmespath.functions.Functions):\nAttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Functions'\n",

Answer (score 1):

- Loop through each asset
- Print the browser URL of the item if it ends with `x64.AppImage`

Solution not using `JMESPath`:

```
- name: Filter reply
  debug: var=item.browser_download_url
  with_items: "{{ json_reply.json.assets }}"
  when: item.browser_download_url | regex_search('x64.AppImage$')
```

Answer (score 1):

As @helloV said, you can accomplish this using Ansible loops, although there's no reason to involve a regular expression match.   You can use the same test you're already using:

```
- name: Filter reply
  debug:
    var: item.browser_download_url
  with_items: "{{ json_reply.json.assets }}"
  when: item.name.endswith('x64.AppImage')
```

The root problem would appear to be an Ansible bug.  The error comes from [the following check](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/blob/develop/jmespath/functions.py#L110) in the `jmespath` library:

```
      if actual_typename not in allowed_types:
          raise exceptions.JMESPathTypeError(
              function_name, current,
              self._convert_to_jmespath_type(actual_typename), types)
```

At the point this code is called, the data type of values in your json response is `AnsibleUnsafeText`, where as `allowed_types` is `[str, unicode]`.  I think the transformation of values from native types to the `AnsibleUnsafeText` type probably is some sort of standard Ansible module behavior being imposed by the `uri` module.  We can work around it by using `curl` instead, like this:

```
- name: Get list of Rambox releases
  command: >
    curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/latest"
  register: json_reply
```

And then:

```
- name: Filter reply
  debug:
    var: item.browser_download_url
  with_items: >
    {{ json_reply.stdout|from_json|json_query('assets[?ends_with(name, `x64.AppImage`)]') }}
```

Comment: The problem is discussed here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299#issuecomment-331068246 and a workaround is to use `| to_json | from_json |`

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov The workaround you proposed is the best solution, as it avoids having to loop all over the document. If you post the answer, I'll accept it.